Excel lookup formula for column name in min value of alternate column
I'm trying to do something like this
x      col1  col2  col3 col4 col5 col6 result1 result2
row 1   18    54    84   32   61   34    col1    col4
row 2   68    11    8    95   41   658   col3    col2

result1 is col1 because 18 is the lowest of col1, col3. col5
result2 is col4 because 32 is the lowest of col2, col4. col6
I found a formula like this
=INDEX(B1:D1,1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))

which I modified to =INDEX(C1,E1,G1,I1,K1,M1,O1,1,MATCH(MIN(C2,E2,G2,I2,K2,M2,O2),C2,E2,G2,I2,K2,M2,O2,0)) (Yea i kinda botched it)

What are your columns called in real life? is this a Budget vs Actuals scenario?

Just some values

Consider using an identifier in the row above the table header. Then you can use a very basic MinIF or MinIfs function to summarize, e.g. in cell G3 of the screenshot:
=MINIFS(Table1[@[col1]:[col6]],$A$1:$F$1,"budget")


If the extra row upsets your workbook layout, just hide it.

Or you can make the extra row's font colour "white" to make it invisible...

That is a very lazy solution making assumptions not stated in the question.

@Michal I disagree (obviously) :). In many cases, adding helper rows/columns/cells can be very useful in simplifying the formulas needed to arrive at the desired output.  Both yours and my suggestion work equally fine, but just looking at the data and the formula, some users will find my suggestion easier to understand and to remember.  I am perfectly capable of writing a totally obscure formula, but when I come back to the scenario in a year or so, I'll know immediately what the Minifs() formula does, whereas the version nesting Min(), IF(),Mod() etc, will take a lot longer to get back into.

Yes. other programming languages need an IDE for debugging. while Excel helper columns provide a natural advantage when it comes to debugging or easier inspections.

A simple MIN solution:
Even-numbered columns:
=MIN(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A3:F3),2)=0,A3:F3))

Odd-numbered columns:
=MIN(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A3:F3),2)=1,A3:F3))



The formula in K25 and drag right and down:
=LET(seq,INDEX(B26:G26,1,SEQUENCE(1,3,1,2)),INDEX(B$25:G$25,1,MATCH(MIN(seq),seq,1)*2-1))
The result


Ok, now I finally realised OP's desired results is column name, not the smallest number. then INDEX and MATCH is inevitable...

Or you can do this:
For col1, 3, 5:
=INDEX(SORT(INDEX(VSTACK($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2),{1;2},SEQUENCE(1,3,1,2)),2,1,TRUE),1,1)
For col2, 4, 6;
=INDEX(SORT(INDEX(VSTACK($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2),{1;2},SEQUENCE(1,3,2,2)),2,1,TRUE),1,1)
First, below will get col1, 3, 5 data, together with the header:
=INDEX(VSTACK($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2),{1;2},SEQUENCE(1,3,1,2))
Then sort the data by ascending order, and take the first:

